# How can i redirect to another url on ajax request using javaEE Filter

Tags: java

I am creating a web filter for my application, which uses an external authentication provider. This web filter should redirect to the login page if there is no cookie, or if the token inside the cookie is invalid or expired. This works fine with non-AJAX requests, but with AJAX requests, it is making an AJAX request to the login form URL instead of simply redirecting to that URL using a non-AJAX request. I want the filter to redirect the user to the login page using a non-AJAX request, so the user can directly enter their credentials.

```java
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/*")
public class SecurrityFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        
        String requestURI = httpRequest.getRequestURI();

        if (requestURI.matches(".*(css|jpg|png|gif|js)")) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        
        Cookie[] cookies = httpRequest.getCookies();
        boolean cookieExists = false;
        String cookieValue = null;
        if (cookies != null) {
            for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                if ("miCookie".equals(cookie.getName())) {
                    cookieExists = true;
                    cookieValue = cookie.getValue();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        
        
        if (!cookieExists || !isActiveSession(cookieValue)) {
            if (isAjaxRequest(httpRequest)) {
                //Redirect to http://localhost:8081/login/database using GET method and not using an ajax request 
                return;     
            } else {
                httpResponse.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8081/login/database");
                return;
            }
        }
        
        chain.doFilter(request, response);      
    }
```

Comment: No way, you can't do that.

Comment: What do you recommend?

Comment: You want to redirect user with the non-ajax request but why did you redirect it with ajax-request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the issue

```java
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        
        if (isStaticFileRequest(httpRequest)) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        
        Optional<String> cookie = getCookie(httpRequest);
        if (cookie.isEmpty() || !isActiveSession(cookie.get())) {
            if (isAjaxRequest(httpRequest)) {
                HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession(false);
                session.invalidate();
            } else {
                httpResponse.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8081/login/database");
                return;
            }
        }
        
        chain.doFilter(request, response);      
    }
```